# How to create a string from char array without copying it?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, char

I have a very big char array that I need to convert to string in order to use Regex on it.
But it's so big that I get `OutOfMemoryException` when I pass that to string constructor.

I know that string is *immutable* and therefore it *shouldn't be* possible to specify its underlying character collection but I need a way to use regular expressions on that without copying the whole thing.

How do I get that array?

- I get it from a file using `StreamReader`. I know the starting position and the length of the content to read, `Read` and `ReadBlock` methods need me to supply a `char[]` buffer.

So here are the things I want to know:

- Is there a way to specify a string's underlaying collection? (Does it even keep its chars in an array?)
- ...or using Regex directly on a char array?
- ...or getting the part of the file directly as string?

Comment: What's the regex? If it's simple enough you could replace it with code that walks the `char[]`.

Comment: @Matt: Unfortunately I can't. It's a pretty long and complex parser.

Comment: @Jon: All the contents of a file that's around 1GB, usually.

Comment: If your char array is greater than `Int32.MaxValue` then what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Are there any characters that are guaranteed _not_ to be matched that you could use to split the `char[]` into smaller strings?

Comment: @DStanley: You have a point, yes I think I can split it but although it _may not_ throw an OOM exception, it would still copy the blocks I already have in memory. It can be useful though, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I would argue that a "long and complex parser" made out of regex isn't using the right tool for the job. You might end up with more lines of code, but a more explicit parser is probably better. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser or https://irony.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=expression%20grammar%20sample&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

If you have a character or pattern that you could search for that is guaranteed NOT to be in the pattern you're trying to find, you could scan the array for that character and create smaller strings to process individually.  Process would be something like:

```
char token = '|';
int start = 0;
int length = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++;)
{
    if(charArray[i] == token)
    {
        string split = new string(charArray,start,length);
        // check the string using the regex

        // reset the length
        length = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        length++;
    }
}
```

That way you're copying smaller segments of the string that would be GCed after each attempt versus the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

I would think your best bet would be to read multiple char[] chunks into individual strings that overlap with a certain dimension. This way you'd be able to perform your Regex on the individual chunks, and the overlap would provide you the ability to ensure that a "break" in the chunks doesn't break the search pattern. In a psuedo-code manner:

```
int chunkSize = 100000;
int overLap = 2000;

for(int i = 0; i < myCharArray.length; i += chunkSize - overlap)
{
    // Grab your array chunk into a partial string
    // By having your iteration slightly smaller than 
    // your chunk size you guarantee not to miss any 
    // character groupings. You just need to make sure
    // your overlap is sufficient to cover the expression
    string chunk = new String(myCharArray.Skip(i).Take(chunkSize).ToArray());
    // run your regex
}
```

Comment: A comment: There's no reason to use Linq methods `Skip` and `Take`. There's [an overload of the string constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx) to do stuff like this. Also, the Linq method `ToArray()` will copy the data an additional time.

Comment: +1. Reading with overlapped chunks seems to be reasonable approach for matching with unknown regex in C#. Comment on comment: I think it is ok to use Skip/Take in sample as it shows intent well, and it clearly wrong thing to do so unlikely be used directly as copy-paste.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It was just meant to be psuedo-code and rather than looking up the very best c# method I went with something I type out regularly that got my point across. If someone were to implement the above code verbatim I'd question their sanity.

Answer (score 0):

One rather ugly option would be to use an unmanaged RegEx library (like the POSIX regular expression library) and unsafe code. You can obtain a byte * pointer to the char array and pass it directly to the unmanaged library, then marshal the responses back.

```
fixed (byte * pArray = largeCharArray)
{
   // call unmanaged code with pArray
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher, what you should be using is a [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.100).aspx). This class was designed exclusively so you could manipulate very large files. From the MSDN documentation:

> A memory-mapped file maps the contents of a file to an application’s
>   logical address
>       space. Memory-mapped files enable programmers to work with extremely large files because
>       memory can be managed concurrently, and they allow complete, random access to a file
>       without the need for seeking. Memory-mapped files can also be shared across multiple
>       processes.

Once you got your memory mapped file, check out [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649239/id-like-to-apply-a-regex-efficiently-to-an-entire-file) on how to apply RegEx to the memory mapped file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: -1. Not sure why using MemoryMappedFile would be better than StreamReader (one would have to deal with encodings by hand)... also unclear where to get matching C#  implementation for Java's code for running Regex on byte arrays.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - MemoryMappedFile is better than StreamReader because StreamReader reads the entire file into memory. MemoryMappedFile partitions the file into windows or views that allows you to operate on a specific region of the file. MemoryMappedFile only reads in the amount of bytes that you need, rather than the whole thing.

Comment: @icemanind: Wrong.  StreamReader does not read the entire file into memory.