# How to create token containing white spaces lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene 5.4.0, I am using StandardAnalyzer to tokenize the source, it removes all the whitespaces from source while creating tokens.

Is their any way or any other analyzer in lucene which doesn't remove spaces while creating indexes?

Please help.

Comment: Do you want to tokenize based on other characters, or just not have the value modified at all? I don't quite understand, what you would want to search for afterwards.

Comment: i don't want the value to be modified while indexing

Comment: Okay. Then check out http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html as a starting point. There's also this other question, which is old but should still be the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564029/how-to-control-indexing-a-field-in-lucene-4-0

Comment: Text field removes all the space while tokenizing the text and stringfield does have a limit and if we try to tokenize a large file with string field, it throws exception

Comment: please suggest something, which can tokenize large files without removing spaces.

Comment: I think you would need to create a custom analyzer. But I have no experience in that, sorry. Maybe this blog post can help you: http://www.citrine.io/blog/2015/2/14/building-a-custom-analyzer-in-lucene

Comment: If your goal is to run regex queries over the entire contents of long text files, lucene is frankly not a very good tool to accomplish that.

Comment: Could you post an example with input and output expected?  I don't know if you want a unique token or other.

Comment: @femtoRgon: Can you suggest any other tool which can run regex on large text files?

Comment: Nothing terribly clever.  [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), I suppose.  There are a few questions out there on the topic ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017480/regex-search-pattern-in-very-large-file) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044584/find-a-string-in-a-very-large-formatted-text-file-in-java) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649239/id-like-to-apply-a-regex-efficiently-to-an-entire-file))